# how to select specific rows and columns of a double array in numpy to form a submatrix?

Tags: numpy

say I have a numpy list of lists:

```
import numpy as np
ab=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,3,6]])
```

Now say I want to have the submatrix the first two rows and column 1 and 3, I would do

```
print(ab[0:2,[1,3]])
```

Now if I want row 0 and 2 and columns 1 and 3, I would try:

```
print(ab[np.array([0,2]),np.array([1,3])])
```

But then I get :

```
[3 6]
```

This is entries wise seeking and not rows and columns wise submatrixing.

How do you do it?

Comment: In a situation where you are selecting rows/columns with static steps, you can do something like this, `print(ab[0:3:2, 1:4:2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select sub-arrays with two broadcastable indices arrays, like `array[arr_1, arr2]`, it will match each element of `arr_1` to `arr_2` and select corresponding element of `array`. If you wish to select all rows in `arr_1` and all columns in `arr_2`, the most elegant way would be using `np.ix_`. The code would be:

```
ab[np.ix_(np.array([0,2]),np.array([1,3]))]
```

output:

```
[[2 4]
 [4 3]]
```

About `np.ix_`: From [numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html): ***This function takes N 1-D sequences and returns N outputs with N dimensions each, such that the shape is 1 in all but one dimension and the dimension with the non-unit shape value cycles through all N dimensions.***

Which means you can extend this to ANY dimension array. For `array` of N dimensions, calling `np.ix_(arr_1, arr_2, ..., arr_N)` will create N indices array, each will cycle through all `arr_i` rows of dimension `i` in `array`.